# Google Chrome doesn't have a bookmark auto-sync when a user presses CTRL-D?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, google-bookmarks

It seems that Google Chrome can easily make use of its online bookmark storage when a user presses CTRL-D to store the bookmark on the local machine, but choose not to do that?

When a user is signed in to Google, which would usually be the case if the user uses gmail, then when the user presses CTRL-D to add a bookmark, it could be convenient to also add that to Google's online bookmark (either have a checkbox for adding it or set in the Options)

(if signed in, our bookmarks are on:)
http://www.google.com/bookmarks

That way, no matter which computer we go to, we always have our bookmarks handy.

But seems like there is no such feature and the closest we have from Google is this solution?

http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=100215

Answer (score 4):

google-chrome [now](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/08/sync-google-chrome-bookmarks.html) (for a while already) has bookmark-syncing (and it does this by storing them on [docs.google.com](http://docs.google.com)).

you can also choose to pick from a list of extensions which access google-bookmarks from within chrome:

- https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fhaicgmeeafgboeobjagfmlcdhbkijhf
- https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mnedccijmniojgaehpjebjfpkmafecho
- https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/lhpnfegocflcdlbjpihgfgcfbahnmdff
- https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jmepkeboidbjfocdlmfpokleckfbmidc

Comment: up to this date, google.com/bookmarks stays very alive and still disconnected from chrome bookmarks.

Comment: yeah, they have another del.iocio.us right there on their plate and they chose not to eat it